# Unable to retrieve the data from ckeditor jquery plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have spent the last several hours trying to simply post the data (text/html) that was entered in the ckeditor (textarea) to the PHP file.

Their API claims that the data automatically posts the data on form submissions, but it does not, it returns nothing.

EDIT: here is the real code:

```
    <?php
    require("fns.php");
    // grab tab content from database
    $tab = array();
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tabs";
    $db_conn = db_connect();
    $results = mysql_query($query,$db_conn);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
    $tab[]= $row;
    }

// form validation
if($_POST['btnSave'])
{
    // grab selected tab ID
    $tabId = $_POST['tabId'];
    $title = $_POST['txtTitle'];
    $content = $_POST['ckeditor'];


    // all fields required
    if(isset($tabId) && isset($title) && isset($content))
    {   
        // update recorde where id = tabId
        $query = "UPDATE tabs SET title = '$title', content = '$content' WHERE id = $tabId";
        if($content !== "")
        {
            if(mysql_query($query,$db_conn))
            {
                $message = "<h3 style='color:#003300;'>Changes Saved!</h3><br /><p>".$content."</p>";
                header("Location:testtabs.php");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $message ="<h3 style='color: #950000;'>Content cannot be blank!</h3>";
        }
    }
}
```

?>

```
    <!-- in head section -->
      <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // inflate ckeditor
    $('#ckeditor').ckeditor();
    //track selected tab
    var currentId = -1; 
        // Tab initialization
        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
         select: function(event, ui){
        /*
        ui.index: zero based index selected tab 
        ui.tab: anchor element of the selected tab
        ui.panel: element containing the content for the selected tab
        */

        // get current tab ID for php script
        var currentId = ui.index + 1;
        $("#tabId").val(currentId);
        var tabName = $(ui.tab).text();
        var content = $(ui.panel).html();
        // swap title
        $( '#title' ).val( tabName );
        // swap content
        $("#ckeditor").val(content);
    }   
});
```

});

```
    <body>
    <?php  echo $message; ?>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"><?php echo $tab[0]['title'];?></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2"><?php echo $tab[1]['title'];?></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3"><?php echo $tab[2]['title'];?></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="content"> 
               <?php echo $tab[0]['content'];  ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div class="content"> 
               <?php echo $tab[1]['content'];  ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <div class="content"> 
               <?php echo $tab[2]['content'];  ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']) && ($_SESSION['account_type'] == 'ADMIN')) 
    {
        // display editor with tab 1 content
        ?>
        <table id="tab-editor">
            <form action = 'testtabs.php' method ='post'>
            <input type="hidden" id="tabId" name ="tabId" value="-1"/>
                <tr><td>Title: <input type='text' name='txtTitle' id='title' value='<?php echo $tab[0]['title'];?>'/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Tab Content:</td></tr><tr><td> <textarea name='ckeditor' id='ckeditor' class='tab-editor'><?php //echo $tab[0]['content'];?></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='submit' name='btnSave' value='Save Changes' /></td>
            </form>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: have you check data in your $_POST array

Comment: it works fine for me, seems like the correct way to do it. do you get any errors in the console? we're not talking about php, only JS right?  i mean, alert(data) or console.log(data) should show you the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverted back to the traditional ckeditor javascript, works fine now...

```
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor' );
    // Tab initialization
// Tab initialization
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
        /*
        ui.index: zero based index selected tab 
        ui.tab: anchor element of the selected tab
        ui.panel: element containing the content for the selected tab
        */

        // get current tab ID for php script
        var currentId = ui.index + 1;
        $("#tabId").val(currentId);
        var tabName = $(ui.tab).text();
        var content = $(ui.panel).html();
        // swap title
        $( '#title' ).val( tabName );
        // swap content
        CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor'].setData(content);

    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor create an istance of CKEditor from a textarea (maybe even from other elements, I don't know that) using the content of the textarea to populate the editor.
Anyway when you use jQuery:

```
$('#ckeditor').val("Initial text (test)");
```

you're putting text inside the textarea tag.
After you create a CKEditor instance you'll need to use CKEditor methods to get the data:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/

Specifically I think you'll need:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData

PS: sorry for my bad english

**EDIT:** hadn't seen the edit, sorry

Comment: works fine with .val() for me, used to on many website and tested under all browsers, old versions too

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone! Perhaps I over simplified the code...the place in which the $('ckeditor').val() is changed occurs in a jquery tab select event. It works fine outside of thise select event, but fails inside the event

Comment: I receive an empty string on $_POST, I have read that ckeditor returns the value as any normal form element does, but as a jquery plugin is doesn't seem to.

Comment: I think we need more information: how the val is changed? What exactly do the select event? Do you have only one ckeditor or more than one? (maybe one for each tab?)
Sorry to ask that much, but without the real code is difficult to help (at least for me).

Comment: I am using one ckeditor to edit all three tabs independently.